# Deep Merge of Arrays in Vanilla Js not working as expected

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I made a codepen to demonstrate my Problem:
https://codepen.io/milenoi-the-sans/pen/vYmzyOj

I have a object that contains several arrays.

I want to change some values in the array by clicking on buttons.

My Problem: The Code works as expected using

```
   $series = $.extend(true, [], arr[2]);
```

But not in Vanilla JS using

```
$series = [...[], ...arr[2]];
```

I want to change a value onclick by multiplying it with a number.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you!

```js
let arr = {
  2: [{
    label: "Label 1",
    data: [
      [1627776000000, 100]
    ]
  }]
}

let series = null;

let update = function(count) {
  //$series = [...[], ...arr[2]];
  //$series = $.extend(true, [], arr[2]);
  $series = [...arr[2]];

  $series.forEach(($el, index) => {
    let $value = 0;

    $series[index].data.forEach(($ele, subIndex) => {
      $value = $series[index].data[subIndex][1];
      $value = count * $value;
      $series[index].data[subIndex][1] = $value;
    });
    document.querySelector('.text').textContent = $value;

  });

};

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(($button) => {
  $button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    update(this.getAttribute('data-count'));
  }, false);
});
```

```css
.text {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button data-count="2">Factor 2</button>
<button data-count="3">Factor 3</button>
<button data-count="4">Factor 4</button>
<button data-count="5">Factor 5</button>

<div class="text"></div>
```

**Expected Output**

Clicking on Button should multiply 100 with value of date-count (2,3,4...) so i expect

200
300
400

works on first click. but then it multiplies with the given value.

When i replace
$series = $.extend(true, [], arr[2]);

it works as expected.

Comment: why don't you just `$series = [...arr[2]];`?

Comment: Hi, you can also use Stackoverflow code snippet. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: @ikhvjs also [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992)

Comment: 1) What's your expected output? `2) `arr` is an object`.

Comment: Sorry i updated my Post with the necessary Code

Comment: i need to replace some parts of the objects with a new calculated value. I tried to simplify this in the example to avoid unneeded complexity. Sorry, i know my example makes not really sense. It is legacy code and i want to replace jQuery with vanilla js. I wonder what i have to do to replace $.extend(true, [], arr[2]); to get it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you change reference array variable. for copy not reference variable you can
use

```
$series = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr[2]))
```

Comment: OMG. You made it. I wondered hours for hours. thank you so much.

Comment: So jQuery takes this into account automatically with the extend method?

Comment: it simply deep clone the object

Comment: @MeepMeep it is custom here to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: I did, @vanowm. Sorry im a new member of the club. try to do it the correct way. I highly appreciate all your help.